# Is it possible to create a python dictionary with keys that can accept a variety of forms?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

```
data = (1,1,1,1,1)

dict_letters = {(1,1,1,1,1) : 'A',
                (0,1,1,0,1) : 'B',
                (1,1,1,1,1) : 'C',   
                (1,0,1,0,1) : 'D'}

def search():
            for key in dict_letters:
                if data == key:
                    print(dict_letters[key])

search()

#when running, this would result in only 'C' being printed; 'A' was never printed
```

Previously in my code, I obtained a unique 5 item tuple that was made up of 0's and 1's (the `data` tuple). The 5 items were essential for differentiating most letters such as 'B' and 'D' from the rest in my dictionary. However, I was faced with a problem when there were two keys that had the same 5 items, so I added 10 more items (other identifying data) to the tuple to help further differentiate the keys; this is an excerpt from my current dictionary:

```
data = (0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
data = (0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
data = (0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)

#x = 0 or 1
dict_letters = {(1,1,1,1,1,x,x,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'A',
                (0,1,1,0,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'B',
                (1,1,1,1,1,x,x,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'C',    
                (1,1,0,0,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'D'}

def search():
            for key in dict_letters:
                if data == key:
                    print(dict_letters[key])

search()

#I need to find a way for all of the data tuples to print 'B' after running the program
```

In this excerpt, I have only created conditions for 1 of the additional items to differentiate 'A' from 'C'. I was wondering if it was possible to disregard if the other 9 additional items were 0 or 1 since they are not useful in the differentiation of these two keys (the items I wish to disregard are marked with `x`). I would also like to disregard the 10 additional items for 'B' and 'D' because the first 5 items are sufficient for identification. For example, I want a way for `(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`,`(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)`,`(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)`, and etc to be all read as 'B' without coding 2047 extra keys for 'B'.

I tried setting `x = 0 or 1`, and `x = 0 and 1` before the dictionary but these does not work since I found that the key is then set to `(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)` for some reason after running the program.

Note: I am looking at using all the additional items at least once in the future, so removing any of the 10 additional items is not an option.

I am also relatively new to Python so I would appreciate it if you could make your answers as simple as possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can I create a single dictionary entry that allows many different keys to output a single value? Please see "For example, I want a way...".

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please give us more context so we can suggest a better solution than that dict with the crazy tuple keys.

Comment: It looks like your keys of tuples are just binary representation of integers. Why not use that?

Comment: @PM2Ring I tried to give more context behind my project but I'm not sure what else I can tell you. Do my edits give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You can't have 2 of the same key in a dictionary.

Comment: @Dan Provide exact input-output please.

Comment: Your edits tell us a little more about your solution Y, but we need to know the X problem so we can offer an alternative to Y.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some kind of wildcard in the dictionary key. Is that it?

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that is to put something like regular expressions in the keys. Convert your tuple to a string, then loop through the dictionary looking for a key that matches the string with `re.search()`.

Comment: A dict gives you fast lookup, but if you have to loop over all the keys to perform your searches there's not much point in using a dict, you might as well use a list of (key, value) tuples, which allows you to have duplicate keys.

Comment: @PM2Ring It's a bit difficult to describe my input. I'm using the Leap Motion Device to receive hand coordinates in 3D space. I found a way to process the data and code if someone's finger is up or down, where finger down is `0` and finger up is `1`. I then used append to collect all the values into the following 5 item tuple representing: thumb up/down, index up/down, middle up/down, ring up/down, and pinky up/down, therefore creating a code such as `(0,1,1,1,1)` where thumb is the only finger that is down.

Comment: The 10 additional items are the same idea. They are codes for if two fingers are touching, as `0` means that two certain fingers are touching and `1` means that the two fingers are not touching each other. For example, the first item after the 5 original items tells me if the thumb and index are touching.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. What's the connection between the bits and the letters? And how many different letters are in the collection?

Comment: @PM2Ring Could you please explain what you mean by bits? I'm not familiar with them unfortunately. The `0` and `1` are just an integer code that I set to make reading my data easier, if that is what you're asking. A dictionary entry such as `(0,1,1,1,1) : 'A'` would mean that I would be able to print 'A' when someone uses my program and displays a hand with only the thumb down.

Comment: The bits are the zeroes and ones. So does your full `dict_letters` collection only have the 26 uppercase letters, or does it have other symbols too? I have an idea for an efficient solution, and I don't really need to know how many symbols are in `dict_letters`, but it may be relevant for other people's solutions.

Comment: I currently have 12 uppercase letters, but my goal is to add dictionary entries for the rest of the alphabet and for as many static symbols as there is in ASL. (I'm basing my identification with ASL hand symbols). In reality, `(1,0,0,0,0)` is actually 'A' and `(0,1,1,1,1)` is 'B'. However, the letters that I need the 10 additional items for differentiation are 'M', 'N', and 'S', which are all hand symbols where all the fingers are down or `(0,0,0,0,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We *can* use a plain `dict` for this task, we just have to build all of the possible keys for each letter. Your key tuples contain 15 items, with each item having 2 different values so there's a maximum of only 2**15 = 32768 different patterns, that's quite small on a modern machine.

We can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all the patterns efficiently. `product` effectively creates nested `for` loops from the args you pass it. Here's a short illustration of the technique. The following code generates all the patterns corresponding to `10XX01`.

```
from itertools import product

for t in product(*[(1,), (0,), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0,), (1,)]):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Here's some code that uses the data given in the question to build a `dict` you can use for your searches. We use the `dict.get` method so that if you look up a pattern that isn't in the dict the code returns `None`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import product

#x = 0 or 1
X = 'x'
letter_patterns = {
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, X, X, 1, X, X, X, X, X, X, X): 'A',
    (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X): 'B',
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, X, X, 0, X, X, X, X, X, X, X): 'C',
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X): 'D',
}

def make_dict(letter_patterns):
    ''' Build a dict of all the bit patterns for each letter '''
    xlate = {0: (0,), 1: (1,), X: (0, 1)}
    letter_dict = {}
    # Generate all of the (0, 1) combinations for each X in each pattern
    for pattern, letter in letter_patterns.items():
        for key in product(*[xlate[u] for u in pattern]):
            letter_dict[key] = letter
    return letter_dict

# test

letter_dict = make_dict(letter_patterns)

test_items = [
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'A'),
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 'A'),
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'A'),
    ((0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 'B'),
    ((0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'B'),
    ((0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 'B'),
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'C'),
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 'C'),
    ((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'C'),
    ((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'D'),
    ((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 'D'),
    ((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 'D'),
    ((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 'Z'),
]

# Check that each test key gets the correct letter, or returns
# None if the key isn't in letter_dict
for key, true_letter in test_items:
    letter = letter_dict.get(key)
    print(key, true_letter, letter, letter == true_letter)
```

**output**

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) A A True
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) A A True
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) A A True
(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) B B True
(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) B B True
(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1) B B True
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) C C True
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) C C True
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) C C True
(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) D D True
(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) D D True
(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) D D True
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) Z None False
```

This code runs correctly on both Python 2 and 3 (tested on 2.6.6 and 3.6.0). You can make it slightly more efficient on Python 2 by changing

```
for pattern, letter in letter_patterns.items():
```

to

```
for pattern, letter in letter_patterns.iteritems():
```

---

The tuples in `letter_patterns` are not very convenient, especially if you want to put a lot of symbols into `letter_patterns`. To reduce the typing, rather than using those tuples we can use strings. Here's a variation of the above code that does that. The resulting `letter_dict` still uses tuple keys, since I assume that's what you get from your Leap Motion Device hardware.

```
letter_patterns = {
    'A': '11111xx1xxxxxxx',
    'B': '01101xxxxxxxxxx',
    'C': '11111xx0xxxxxxx',
    'D': '11001xxxxxxxxxx',
}

def make_dict(letter_patterns):
    ''' Build a dict of all the bit patterns for each letter '''
    xlate = {'0': (0,), '1': (1,), 'x': (0, 1)}
    letter_dict = {}
    # Generate all of the (0, 1) combinations for each X in each pattern
    for letter, pattern in letter_patterns.items():
        for key in product(*[xlate[u] for u in pattern]):
            letter_dict[key] = letter
    return letter_dict
```

Comment: For some reason, it gives me the following error when I try to run it: `File "Project.py", line 210, in make_dict \\
    letter_dict[key] = letter \\
NameError: free variable 'letter_dict' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`. Other than this, I think you've actually completely solved my problem!

Comment: @Dan I think you might have made a copy and paste error. The line `letter_dict = {}` creates the assignment to `letter_dict`, so `letter_dict[key] = letter` is a valid reference to `letter_dict`. Before adding my code to your existing project first try running **exactly** what I have here.

Comment: @Dan Make sure you get the indentation correct. I suspect you accidentally pasted my function inside another function.

Comment: Both versions worked and yes, I found out that I incorrectly indented your code when I integrated it into my project. I'm happy to say, though, that the code works perfectly in my project! I want to thank you for walking me through this and spending the last 2 hours helping me out. I truly appreciate what you've done for me.

Comment: @Dan My pleasure! It was an interesting puzzle to work on, and I wish you good luck in developing your software. And of course, if you get stuck again, you can always ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that given some `tuple` as key, you want some entries in this `tuple` to be ignored if they do not match an existing key exactly.

You can do that by implementing your own dictionary-like class with the help of `collections.UserDict` and a custom `__getitem__` method.

The following implementation assumes that entries in the `tuple` are either `1` or `0`. Without that assumption, it would have to traverse all keys.

```
from UserDict import UserDict
# for Python 3 use this import instead:
# from collections import UserDict

from itertools import product

class WildcardDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, args):
        item, *wildcards = args

        try:
            return self.data[item]
        except KeyError:
            for xs in product((0, 1), repeat=len(wildcards)):
                xs = iter(xs)
                item = tuple(next(xs) if i in wildcards else x for i, x in enumerate(item))
                if item in self.data:
                    return self.data[item]
        raise KeyError(args)

d = WildcardDict()

d[0, 1, 1, 0, 1] = 'B'

print(d[(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), ]) # 'B'
print(d[(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 2, 4]) # 'B'
```

Note that `dict` item lookup is usually *O(1)*, although this makes it *O(2<sup>k</sup>)* where *k* is the number of wildcards. In particular, this means that if the number of wildcards was ever to grow, you would be better using a `list` where lookup would be *O(n)*.

Comment: I'd use "key" rather than "item", to be consistent with the fact that `dict.items` yields (key, value) pairs.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've always used item and PyCharm automatically complete the signature with 'item'. So I don't want to get too far away from that as some might be accustomed to that nomenclature.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I really like your method but I'm still unsure about if it solves all my problems. (Unfortunately I am not able to install 'collections' for some reason so I'll just tentatively ask potential questions here). Say my `data` tuple is `(0,1,0,1,0)` and a dictionary entry reads `(0,1,x,0,x) : 'B'`. My understanding is that the function will try `(0,1,0,1,0)`, which doesn't work, and then `(0,1,0,1)`. If this continues, soon it will reach `(0,1)`, which does work, and it will incorrectly print 'B'.

Comment: @Dan you do not have to install collections, it's a standard library. As for the 2nd and 4th index what is special about them? Will it always be those that are overlooked?

Comment: @Dan Although, are you using Python2.7? Because if it is the case you must do from UserDict import UserDict instead

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I would like the 2nd and 4th index in this example to be a kind of wildcard, as it will accept 0 or 1 as long as the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd indexes are equivalent to their counterparts in the `data` tuple. I'm just not sure how to make the 2nd and 4th indexes 'wildcards'.

Comment: @Dan the solution is similar, I'll adapt it. Also, just confirm that you are using Python2.7, as stated above you then need to sdo from UserDict import UserDict

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yes, I am using python 2.7 because the Leap Motion Device packages are only compatible with this version of python. Thank you for informing me about how to get UserDict in 2.7...that was the issue that prevented me from following along with your code, not installing collections.

Comment: @Dan Here, please have a look at this updated solution.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon this solution works well, except for one problem...the 2nd and 4th indexes are not always wildcards. Depending on the data, sometimes the 1st and 3rd will be wildcards, or in some cases, only the 5th index will be a wildcard. How do I account for the position of the wildcard for each symbol? Do I need to make a separate class for each?

Comment: Here are examples of different wildcard `x` positions in my actual code (how it appears in my dictionary): `(0,1,0,0,0,x,0,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'D'`, `(0,0,0,0,0,1,x,0,x,x,x,x,x,x,x) : 'E'`, and `(0,1,1,0,0,x,x,x,x,0,x,x,x,x,x) : 'U'`

Comment: @Dan, we'll need to pass the wildcards to getitem. I have an idea how (as well as a big warning about doing this), I'll add it tomorrow

Comment: @OlivierMelançon thank you for all your help but I think PM 2Ring's method effectively solves my problem. I do appreciate your effort in guiding me through your method, though!

Comment: @Dan Sure, the wildcard system being more complex than what I expected when I wrote my original answer, it makes sense to just generate the whole dict with duplicate keys. Although, if you are still interested, you can have a look at the yet again improved answer. It allows to pass the wildcard indices in to the getitem method inside the brackets [...]